# Unlink object after using Ctrl + L

Tags: linked-data

Blender 2.8

I linked some lights' "Object Data" using Ctrl + L so I could adjust their brightness etc. equally.

I'd now like to "Unlink" some of the lights.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.7, press <kbd>U</kbd> (*Make Single User*) > *Object & Data*.

In 2.8, bottom bar menu > *Object* > *Relations* > *Make Single User* > *Object & Data*.

Comment: I'm using 2.8 - nothing pops up when I press "U". Is that a bug? I can however find "Single User" in Object -> Relations.

Comment: yes, I've corrected  ;)